# 3d motion/hitboxing with threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am attempting to do some simple motion with threejs. My goal is to have a box you can move around that cannot walk through walls. As of right now my motion code looks like this

```js
function handleMotion(mesh) {
    var xClone = mesh.clone();
    xClone.position.x += mesh.velocity.x;
    if (checkColl(xClone, collisionMeshList, [mesh.uuid])) {
        mesh.velocity.x = 0;
    }
    var yClone = mesh.clone();
    yClone.position.y += mesh.velocity.y;
    if (checkColl(yClone, collisionMeshList, [mesh.uuid])) {
        mesh.velocity.y = 0;
    }
    var zClone = mesh.clone();
    zClone.position.z += mesh.velocity.z;
    if (checkColl(zClone, collisionMeshList, [mesh.uuid])) {
        mesh.velocity.z = 0;
    }

    mesh.position.add(mesh.velocity);
}
```

It checks each axis of motion to ensure that it is not going to move into a wall on the next frame. The problem is it does not prevent the cube from moving into the wall, however, once it moves into the wall it prevents the cube move moving *out*.
I also tried adding a "sim step" just to check if it could be increased by increasing the number of calculations it did however led to no change. The code is basically acting like the clones are at the same position as the mesh however I have confirmed they are indeed offset.

Comment: Are your bounds always going to be inside a cube? If so, you can simply use [`Three.Math.clamp()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Math.clamp) to limit your movement in each axis without resorting to physics collision detection.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not. I plan to have a character moving in a dynamic 3d space

Comment: You probably want [a physics library](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Physics-libraries) (which necessarily includes collisions).

Comment: That is probably the best solution however I am trying to minimize the amount of external code I use to the point that I am considering creating my own 3d rendering engine.